# Passing parameter from VB .Net to C (structure)

Tags: .net, c, vb.net, structure, marshalling

I'm trying to pass one structure from VB to C.

this structure has only 2 members.
The problem is that only the first member maintain the value.

I guess that's a problem with the size of each member, but I don't know how to solve.

Example And Code:

VB .Net CODE:

```
<DllImport("UserMode_C.dll")> _
Shared Sub someExample(ByVal handleOfSomething As IntPtr, ByRef Filter As __Structure)
End Sub

 <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
    Structure __Structure
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U8)> Public UsbSerial As ULong
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U8)> Public UsbType As ULong
End Structure

Dim Buffer As New __Structure
Buffer.UsbSerial = 123456
Buffer.UsbType = 8

Device = 123456

someExample(Device, Buffer)
```

C CODE:

```
typedef struct __Structure{
      ULONG  UsbSerial;
      ULONG  UsbType;
}__Structure, *__Structure;

#define DllExport __declspec(dllexport)


EXTERN_C
{

      DllExport void someExample(HANDLE handleOfSomething, __Structure* Filter)
      {
           //
           // Here we have
           //   Filter.UsbSerial = 123456
           //   Filter.UsbType = 0        <<<--- this is wrong! I sent 8.
           /* ... */
      }
}
```

Comment: It, of course, depends on which compiler is used, but traditionally a `long` in C is 32 bits, but a `Long` in VB.NET is 64 bits.  Try using a `UInteger` with `UnManagedType.U4`, instead.

Comment: @StevenDoggart - Since that fixed the OPs problem, you should make it an answer so it can be accepted

Comment: @Mike, Already started doing so :)

Comment: @StevenDoggart It's not traditional for `long` to be 32 bits. However, on Windows a C `long` is always 32 bits. On *nix it tends to be 64 bits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ULong` type in VB.NET is a 64-bit (8-byte) unsigned integer.  On windows, the `ULONG` type in C is a 32-bit (4-byte) unsigned integer (half the size of the VB.NET data type).

To fix it, just change your structure to, use the `UInteger` type with `UnManagedType.U4`, like this:

```
<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>
Structure __Structure
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)> Public UsbSerial As UInteger
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)> Public UsbType As UInteger
End Structure
```

Comment: No assumption necessary. [`ULONG`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx#ULONG) on Windows is `unsigned long` which is indeed 4 bytes wide.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks for the clarification.  I have never used C in windows.  I used to use it a long time ago in DOS, so I wasn't 100% sure what it was anymore.  I figured some expert from the other side of the aisle, like you, would speak up and provide more authoritative info :)  I've updated my answer.